# How to use gulp-webpack with famo.us

Tags: gulp, famo.us, webpack

How do I use webpack with famo.us

I found a seed https://github.com/Vertice/famous-webpack-seed and have seen it in use with grunt before. I was wondering if anyone could help me implement it with Gulp. I don't seem to be able to figure out how to get gulp-webpack to find and use the famous modules. Either through the pre compiled require version or the npm uncompressed version.

Answer (score -1):

No doubt the webpack is useful to those who have lots of gulp specific stuff, and I think it's great to see the number ways of being able to get going with Famo.us is increasing, but I think the official [**generator-famous**](https://github.com/Famous/generator-famous) starter is a lot more fully featured, better documented, and has easier commands IMHO.

Comment: True it is better documented. I guess I should always move to better documented projects regardless of the potential of a newer system. By that logic I really shouldn't be using famo.us either.